# How to detect which row and column clicked in listview in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have one wpf project and in that I have one form and it it I have added one listview. I have loaded total 8 rows in it. And I have additionally added 2 more columns with text as Edit and Remove. Now what I need is on click of Edit and Remove click the respective row column details will come. Like if user click on Edit than the edit code should executes. Same thing with the Remove click also. I am attaching my wpf xaml file code here

```
<ListView x:Name="lstViewIrctcId" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="271" Margin="4,140,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="777" >
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>

                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                    <EventSetter Event="PreviewGotKeyboardFocus" Handler="SelectCurrentItem"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Id" Header="ID" Width="135" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ID}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Count" Header="TOTAL COUNT" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding COUNT}"  />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Name"  Header="NAME" Width="80"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding NAME}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Address"  Header="Address" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ADDRESS}" />
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="Status" Header="Status" Width="80"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding STATUS}" />                        
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="irEdit"  Header="Edit" Width="60">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Edit" MouseLeftButtonUp="Edit_btn_click">

                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="irRemove" Header="Remove" Width="60">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="Edit" MouseLeftButtonUp="Delete_btn_click">

                                </TextBlock>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

I have tried adding the MouseLeftButtonUp in edit and remove and created its methods in .cs file. This detects which column clicked ie. Edit or Remove but I also need the respective row details in order to process the Edit and Remove operations.

Comment: How do you populate your `ListView`?

Answer (score 0):

in your list view xaml you should pass the listview items in a command like :

`Command="{Binding GetSelectedItem}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"`

and in your code, after declaring the command as Relay command or delegateCommand you can call this function

```
public void YourCommandMethod(object obj)
    {
        try
        {
            //Get our list view
            ListView listview = (ListView)obj;
            string sNavigationPath = string.Empty;
            //this is a work around to get selected item without clicking on list view, just the coordinates
            var item = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(listview, Mouse.GetPosition(listview)).VisualHit;
            // find ListViewItem (or null)
            while (item != null && !(item is ListViewItem))
                item = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(item);
            if (item != null)
            {
                //Convert item to Listview
                ListViewItem listviewItem = (ListViewItem)item;
                //Get the data context wich hold the necessary info
                var _dataContext = listviewItem.DataContext;
                //Convert back to our customized listview
                var _list = (ListViewItems)_dataContext;
                // Do whatever you want with your elements

            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StaticElements.showErrorFlyout(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```